# Write output of ansible task to file in proper JSON format

Tags: json, regex, ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm trying to write shell task output to json, but I have the problem of parsing it in a valid one json file.

This is example of shell task output:
`{"firstname": "John", "lastname": "Smith", "user": "john"}`

```
- name: 'Execute script'
  shell: /tmp/script.sh
  register: script_output

- name: 'Output to json'
  local_action:
    module: lineinfile
    dest: output.json
    line: '{{ script_output.stdout }}'
    create: yes
```

After playbook execution, the json file has the following content:

```
{"firstname": "John", "lastname": "Smith", "user": "john"}
{"firstname": "John", "lastname": "Smith", "user": "john"}
{"firstname": "John", "lastname": "Smith", "user": "john"}
```

How can I format the output in the json valid format as attached?

```
[
    {"firstname": "John", "lastname": "Smith", "user": "john"},
    {"firstname": "John", "lastname": "Smith", "user": "john"},
    {"firstname": "John", "lastname": "Smith", "user": "john"}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no ansible `json module` for doing this. But you can use third-party modules like [ansible-jsonpatch](https://github.com/ParticleDecay/ansible-jsonpatch) for this.

Answer (score 0):

That is a simple case and you can use what @JGK has replied with, or you could just define a list and add those json elements to it. Without any modules!

i.e.:

```
  - vars:
      elem:
      - {"firstname": "John", "lastname": "Smith", "user": "john"}
      - {"firstname": "John", "lastname": "Smith", "user": "john"}
      - {"firstname": "John", "lastname": "Smith", "user": "john"}

  - set_fact:
      my_list: []

  - name: add to list
    set_fact:
      my_list: "{{ my_list + [item] }}"
    loop: "{{ elem }}"

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ my_list }}"

  - copy:
      content: "{{ my_list }}"
      dest: ./x.json
    delegate_to: localhost
```

and here's the result validated with json python module or jq:

```
$ jq . x.json
[
  {
    "lastname": "Smith",
    "user": "john",
    "firstname": "John"
  },
  {
    "lastname": "Smith",
    "user": "john",
    "firstname": "John"
  },
  {
    "lastname": "Smith",
    "user": "john",
    "firstname": "John"
  }
]
```

Python:

```
$ python -m json.tool x.json 
[
    {
        "firstname": "John",
        "lastname": "Smith",
        "user": "john"
    },
    {
        "firstname": "John",
        "lastname": "Smith",
        "user": "john"
    },
    {
        "firstname": "John",
        "lastname": "Smith",
        "user": "john"
    }
]
```